# Как в Recyclerview переместить item?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Задача стоит такая, в `RecyclerView` набор элементов, по клику на какой нибудь элемент, он должен уехать вниз в конец списка с анимацией.
Каким образом это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если без анимации, то так (во viewholder):

где `ArrayList<Object> objects` - ваш массив, переданный в адаптер

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Object object = objects.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    objects.remove(getAdapterPosition()); (или objects.remove(object))
                    objects.add(object);
                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

если надо добавить не на последнее, а на конкретное место - используйте `add` с индексом: `add(position,object)`

Comment: Это первое что я сделал. В том то и дело, что нужно с анимацией, не указал в вопросе.

Comment: Добился нужно эффекта

`notifyItemMoved(getAdapterPosition(),list.size()-1);`